# Undefined control sequence help required for plotting a graph

Tags: pgfplots, csv, texpad

When trying to insert a graph plotting a DC transfer curve from Multisim I have been having a minor issue and I'm not sure why. If anyone could explain how to fix this I would be greatly appreciative. The code is the block below and the error is "undefined control sequence". Thank you. Important to note as well the data is in a csv file and is separated by commas.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    
        title = {DC Transfer Characteristic},
        xlabel = {Current (A)},
        ylabel = {Voltage (V)},
        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0, ymin = 0.16,
        xtick = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
        ytick = {0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16},
        legend pos=north west,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    ]
    
    \addplot table[col sep=comma] {test.csv};
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\caption{Current through the 100 $\Omega$ resistor with a variation in the voltage source}
\end{figure}
```

Edit: Min Working Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\title{Laboratory Report 1}
\author{John Doe}

\date{\today}

\maketitle
\newpage

\section{Problem 1}

\paragraph{Question\newline}

Question Text

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,5)
      to [battery2 = $12V$] (0, 0) % The DC power source
      to [short] (2,0)
      to (2, -0) node[ground]() {}
      to [short] (2,0) 
      to [short] (4,0)
      to [short] (4,1)
      to (4, 1) node[nigfete](CD4007NM){CD4007NM} %The transistor
      (CD4007NM.base) node[anchor=east] {}
      (CD4007NM.collector) node[anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm] {}
      (CD4007NM.emitter) node[anchor=north] {}
      (CD4007NM.collector) to[short] ++(0,1)
      (CD4007NM.base) to[short] ++(0,1.26)
      to [short] (4, 2)
      to[R=$100\Omega$] (4, 5) % The resistor
      to [short] (0, 5);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Fig Text}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Answer\newline}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {DC Transfer Characteristic},
        xlabel = {Current (A)},
        ylabel = {Voltage (V)},
        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0, ymin = 0.16,
        xtick = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
        ytick = {0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16},
        legend pos=north west,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    ]
    
    \addplot table[col sep=comma] {Question 1 Graph Results.csv};
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\caption{Fig text}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Data file titled - Question 1 Graph Results.csv:

```
X,Y
1.769000000000000000000000000000,0.000001881220000000000000000000
1.770000000000000000000000000000,0.000001881760000000000000000000
1.771000000000000000000000000000,0.000021185500000000000000000000
1.772000000000000000000000000000,0.000042243900000000000000000000
1.773000000000000000000000000000,0.000063328600000000000000000000
1.774000000000000000000000000000,0.000084418600000000000000000000
1.775000000000000000000000000000,0.000105510000000000000000000000
1.776000000000000000000000000000,0.000126601000000000000000000000
1.777000000000000000000000000000,0.000147691000000000000000000000
1.778000000000000000000000000000,0.000168781000000000000000000000
1.779000000000000000000000000000,0.000189869000000000000000000000
1.780000000000000000000000000000,0.000210955000000000000000000000
1.781000000000000000000000000000,0.000232041000000000000000000000
1.782000000000000000000000000000,0.000253125000000000000000000000
1.783000000000000000000000000000,0.000274207000000000000000000000
1.784000000000000000000000000000,0.000295288000000000000000000000
1.785000000000000000000000000000,0.000316367000000000000000000000
1.786000000000000000000000000000,0.000337445000000000000000000000
1.787000000000000000000000000000,0.000358521000000000000000000000
1.788000000000000000000000000000,0.000379596000000000000000000000
1.789000000000000000000000000000,0.000400670000000000000000000000
1.790000000000000000000000000000,0.000421741000000000000000000000
1.791000000000000000000000000000,0.000442812000000000000000000000
1.792000000000000000000000000000,0.000463880000000000000000000000
1.793000000000000000000000000000,0.000484947000000000000000000000
1.794000000000000000000000000000,0.000506013000000000000000000000
1.795000000000000000000000000000,0.000527077000000000000000000000
1.796000000000000000000000000000,0.000548139000000000000000000000
1.797000000000000000000000000000,0.000569200000000000000000000000
1.798000000000000000000000000000,0.000590260000000000000000000000
1.799000000000000000000000000000,0.000611317000000000000000000000
1.800000000000000000000000000000,0.000632374000000000000000000000
1.801000000000000000000000000000,0.000653428000000000000000000000
1.802000000000000000000000000000,0.000674482000000000000000000000
1.803000000000000000000000000000,0.000695533000000000000000000000
1.804000000000000000000000000000,0.000716583000000000000000000000
1.805000000000000000000000000000,0.000737632000000000000000000000
1.806000000000000000000000000000,0.000758678000000000000000000000
1.807000000000000000000000000000,0.000779724000000000000000000000
1.808000000000000000000000000000,0.000800768000000000000000000000
1.809000000000000000000000000000,0.000821810000000000000000000000
1.810000000000000000000000000000,0.000842851000000000000000000000
1.811000000000000000000000000000,0.000863890000000000000000000000
1.812000000000000000000000000000,0.000884927000000000000000000000
1.813000000000000000000000000000,0.000905963000000000000000000000
1.814000000000000000000000000000,0.000926998000000000000000000000
1.815000000000000000000000000000,0.000948031000000000000000000000
1.816000000000000000000000000000,0.000969062000000000000000000000
1.817000000000000000000000000000,0.000990092000000000000000000000
1.818000000000000000000000000000,0.001011120000000000000000000000
1.819000000000000000000000000000,0.001032147000000000000000000000
1.820000000000000000000000000000,0.001053172000000000000000000000
1.821000000000000000000000000000,0.001074196000000000000000000000
1.822000000000000000000000000000,0.001095218000000000000000000000
1.823000000000000000000000000000,0.001116238000000000000000000000
1.824000000000000000000000000000,0.001137257000000000000000000000
1.825000000000000000000000000000,0.001158274000000000000000000000
1.826000000000000000000000000000,0.001179290000000000000000000000
1.827000000000000000000000000000,0.001200305000000000000000000000
1.828000000000000000000000000000,0.001221317000000000000000000000
1.829000000000000000000000000000,0.001242328000000000000000000000
1.830000000000000000000000000000,0.001263338000000000000000000000
1.831000000000000000000000000000,0.001284346000000000000000000000
1.832000000000000000000000000000,0.001305353000000000000000000000
1.833000000000000000000000000000,0.001326358000000000000000000000
1.834000000000000000000000000000,0.001347361000000000000000000000
1.835000000000000000000000000000,0.001368363000000000000000000000
1.836000000000000000000000000000,0.001389363000000000000000000000
1.837000000000000000000000000000,0.001410362000000000000000000000
1.838000000000000000000000000000,0.001431359000000000000000000000
1.839000000000000000000000000000,0.001452355000000000000000000000
1.840000000000000000000000000000,0.001473349000000000000000000000
1.841000000000000000000000000000,0.001494342000000000000000000000
1.842000000000000000000000000000,0.001515333000000000000000000000
1.843000000000000000000000000000,0.001536322000000000000000000000
1.844000000000000000000000000000,0.001557310000000000000000000000
1.845000000000000000000000000000,0.001578297000000000000000000000
1.846000000000000000000000000000,0.001599281000000000000000000000
1.847000000000000000000000000000,0.001620265000000000000000000000
1.848000000000000000000000000000,0.001641247000000000000000000000
1.849000000000000000000000000000,0.001662227000000000000000000000
1.850000000000000000000000000000,0.001683205000000000000000000000
1.851000000000000000000000000000,0.001704183000000000000000000000
1.852000000000000000000000000000,0.001725158000000000000000000000
1.853000000000000000000000000000,0.001746132000000000000000000000
1.854000000000000000000000000000,0.001767105000000000000000000000
1.855000000000000000000000000000,0.001788076000000000000000000000
1.856000000000000000000000000000,0.001809045000000000000000000000
1.857000000000000000000000000000,0.001830013000000000000000000000
1.858000000000000000000000000000,0.001850979000000000000000000000
1.859000000000000000000000000000,0.001871944000000000000000000000
1.860000000000000000000000000000,0.001892907000000000000000000000
1.861000000000000000000000000000,0.001913869000000000000000000000
1.862000000000000000000000000000,0.001934829000000000000000000000
1.863000000000000000000000000000,0.001955788000000000000000000000
1.864000000000000000000000000000,0.001976745000000000000000000000
1.865000000000000000000000000000,0.001997700000000000000000000000
1.866000000000000000000000000000,0.002018654000000000000000000000
1.867000000000000000000000000000,0.002039607000000000000000000000
1.868000000000000000000000000000,0.002060558000000000000000000000
1.869000000000000000000000000000,0.002081507000000000000000000000
1.870000000000000000000000000000,0.002102455000000000000000000000
1.871000000000000000000000000000,0.002123401000000000000000000000
1.872000000000000000000000000000,0.002144346000000000000000000000
1.873000000000000000000000000000,0.002165289000000000000000000000
1.874000000000000000000000000000,0.002186231000000000000000000000
1.875000000000000000000000000000,0.002207171000000000000000000000
1.876000000000000000000000000000,0.002228110000000000000000000000
1.877000000000000000000000000000,0.002249047000000000000000000000
1.878000000000000000000000000000,0.002269982000000000000000000000
1.879000000000000000000000000000,0.002290916000000000000000000000
1.880000000000000000000000000000,0.002311849000000000000000000000
1.881000000000000000000000000000,0.002332780000000000000000000000
1.882000000000000000000000000000,0.002353709000000000000000000000
1.883000000000000000000000000000,0.002374637000000000000000000000
1.884000000000000000000000000000,0.002395563000000000000000000000
1.885000000000000000000000000000,0.002416488000000000000000000000
1.886000000000000000000000000000,0.002437412000000000000000000000
1.887000000000000000000000000000,0.002458333000000000000000000000
1.888000000000000000000000000000,0.002479253000000000000000000000
1.889000000000000000000000000000,0.002500172000000000000000000000
1.890000000000000000000000000000,0.002521089000000000000000000000
1.891000000000000000000000000000,0.002542005000000000000000000000
1.892000000000000000000000000000,0.002562919000000000000000000000
1.893000000000000000000000000000,0.002583832000000000000000000000
1.894000000000000000000000000000,0.002604743000000000000000000000
1.895000000000000000000000000000,0.002625652000000000000000000000
1.896000000000000000000000000000,0.002646560000000000000000000000
1.897000000000000000000000000000,0.002667466000000000000000000000
1.898000000000000000000000000000,0.002688371000000000000000000000
1.899000000000000000000000000000,0.002709275000000000000000000000
1.900000000000000000000000000000,0.002730177000000000000000000000
1.901000000000000000000000000000,0.002751077000000000000000000000
1.902000000000000000000000000000,0.002771976000000000000000000000
1.903000000000000000000000000000,0.002792873000000000000000000000
1.904000000000000000000000000000,0.002813769000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Do you have an empty line before `title` in your actual document? If so, try removing it. If this does not help. post a *complete* minimal *working* example.

Comment: @abcdefg Yes, the text in the document is exactly as shown above, I've removed that new line (force of habit from programming), but the data still isn't being read in (the axis now draws though). Apologies when you say a complete minimal working example what do you mean?

Comment: A minimal working example starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled (which, in your case, says that you need to also provide us with some data file `test.csv`).

Comment: @abcdefg Is the edit enough info?

Comment: Yes. There may be an issue with the blanks inside the file name `Question 1 Graph Results.csv`. So let's call the file `test.csv`. Then there is a problem with `ymin = 0, ymin = 0.16,`. If I remove `ymin = 0.16,` and use `\addplot table[col sep=comma,x=X,y=Y] {test.csv};` then I do see a nontrivial plot.

Comment: @abcdefg OK, I've renamed the file and it's still not loading the data, also thanks for pointing out the error in the naming of `ymax`. Would you like me to change my code above to the new code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't planning to write an answer but it is hard to clarify this in the comments. Here is what I did.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.csv}
X,Y
1.769000000000000000000000000000,0.000001881220000000000000000000
1.770000000000000000000000000000,0.000001881760000000000000000000
1.771000000000000000000000000000,0.000021185500000000000000000000
1.772000000000000000000000000000,0.000042243900000000000000000000
1.773000000000000000000000000000,0.000063328600000000000000000000
1.774000000000000000000000000000,0.000084418600000000000000000000
1.775000000000000000000000000000,0.000105510000000000000000000000
1.776000000000000000000000000000,0.000126601000000000000000000000
1.777000000000000000000000000000,0.000147691000000000000000000000
1.778000000000000000000000000000,0.000168781000000000000000000000
1.779000000000000000000000000000,0.000189869000000000000000000000
1.780000000000000000000000000000,0.000210955000000000000000000000
1.781000000000000000000000000000,0.000232041000000000000000000000
1.782000000000000000000000000000,0.000253125000000000000000000000
1.783000000000000000000000000000,0.000274207000000000000000000000
1.784000000000000000000000000000,0.000295288000000000000000000000
1.785000000000000000000000000000,0.000316367000000000000000000000
1.786000000000000000000000000000,0.000337445000000000000000000000
1.787000000000000000000000000000,0.000358521000000000000000000000
1.788000000000000000000000000000,0.000379596000000000000000000000
1.789000000000000000000000000000,0.000400670000000000000000000000
1.790000000000000000000000000000,0.000421741000000000000000000000
1.791000000000000000000000000000,0.000442812000000000000000000000
1.792000000000000000000000000000,0.000463880000000000000000000000
1.793000000000000000000000000000,0.000484947000000000000000000000
1.794000000000000000000000000000,0.000506013000000000000000000000
1.795000000000000000000000000000,0.000527077000000000000000000000
1.796000000000000000000000000000,0.000548139000000000000000000000
1.797000000000000000000000000000,0.000569200000000000000000000000
1.798000000000000000000000000000,0.000590260000000000000000000000
1.799000000000000000000000000000,0.000611317000000000000000000000
1.800000000000000000000000000000,0.000632374000000000000000000000
1.801000000000000000000000000000,0.000653428000000000000000000000
1.802000000000000000000000000000,0.000674482000000000000000000000
1.803000000000000000000000000000,0.000695533000000000000000000000
1.804000000000000000000000000000,0.000716583000000000000000000000
1.805000000000000000000000000000,0.000737632000000000000000000000
1.806000000000000000000000000000,0.000758678000000000000000000000
1.807000000000000000000000000000,0.000779724000000000000000000000
1.808000000000000000000000000000,0.000800768000000000000000000000
1.809000000000000000000000000000,0.000821810000000000000000000000
1.810000000000000000000000000000,0.000842851000000000000000000000
1.811000000000000000000000000000,0.000863890000000000000000000000
1.812000000000000000000000000000,0.000884927000000000000000000000
1.813000000000000000000000000000,0.000905963000000000000000000000
1.814000000000000000000000000000,0.000926998000000000000000000000
1.815000000000000000000000000000,0.000948031000000000000000000000
1.816000000000000000000000000000,0.000969062000000000000000000000
1.817000000000000000000000000000,0.000990092000000000000000000000
1.818000000000000000000000000000,0.001011120000000000000000000000
1.819000000000000000000000000000,0.001032147000000000000000000000
1.820000000000000000000000000000,0.001053172000000000000000000000
1.821000000000000000000000000000,0.001074196000000000000000000000
1.822000000000000000000000000000,0.001095218000000000000000000000
1.823000000000000000000000000000,0.001116238000000000000000000000
1.824000000000000000000000000000,0.001137257000000000000000000000
1.825000000000000000000000000000,0.001158274000000000000000000000
1.826000000000000000000000000000,0.001179290000000000000000000000
1.827000000000000000000000000000,0.001200305000000000000000000000
1.828000000000000000000000000000,0.001221317000000000000000000000
1.829000000000000000000000000000,0.001242328000000000000000000000
1.830000000000000000000000000000,0.001263338000000000000000000000
1.831000000000000000000000000000,0.001284346000000000000000000000
1.832000000000000000000000000000,0.001305353000000000000000000000
1.833000000000000000000000000000,0.001326358000000000000000000000
1.834000000000000000000000000000,0.001347361000000000000000000000
1.835000000000000000000000000000,0.001368363000000000000000000000
1.836000000000000000000000000000,0.001389363000000000000000000000
1.837000000000000000000000000000,0.001410362000000000000000000000
1.838000000000000000000000000000,0.001431359000000000000000000000
1.839000000000000000000000000000,0.001452355000000000000000000000
1.840000000000000000000000000000,0.001473349000000000000000000000
1.841000000000000000000000000000,0.001494342000000000000000000000
1.842000000000000000000000000000,0.001515333000000000000000000000
1.843000000000000000000000000000,0.001536322000000000000000000000
1.844000000000000000000000000000,0.001557310000000000000000000000
1.845000000000000000000000000000,0.001578297000000000000000000000
1.846000000000000000000000000000,0.001599281000000000000000000000
1.847000000000000000000000000000,0.001620265000000000000000000000
1.848000000000000000000000000000,0.001641247000000000000000000000
1.849000000000000000000000000000,0.001662227000000000000000000000
1.850000000000000000000000000000,0.001683205000000000000000000000
1.851000000000000000000000000000,0.001704183000000000000000000000
1.852000000000000000000000000000,0.001725158000000000000000000000
1.853000000000000000000000000000,0.001746132000000000000000000000
1.854000000000000000000000000000,0.001767105000000000000000000000
1.855000000000000000000000000000,0.001788076000000000000000000000
1.856000000000000000000000000000,0.001809045000000000000000000000
1.857000000000000000000000000000,0.001830013000000000000000000000
1.858000000000000000000000000000,0.001850979000000000000000000000
1.859000000000000000000000000000,0.001871944000000000000000000000
1.860000000000000000000000000000,0.001892907000000000000000000000
1.861000000000000000000000000000,0.001913869000000000000000000000
1.862000000000000000000000000000,0.001934829000000000000000000000
1.863000000000000000000000000000,0.001955788000000000000000000000
1.864000000000000000000000000000,0.001976745000000000000000000000
1.865000000000000000000000000000,0.001997700000000000000000000000
1.866000000000000000000000000000,0.002018654000000000000000000000
1.867000000000000000000000000000,0.002039607000000000000000000000
1.868000000000000000000000000000,0.002060558000000000000000000000
1.869000000000000000000000000000,0.002081507000000000000000000000
1.870000000000000000000000000000,0.002102455000000000000000000000
1.871000000000000000000000000000,0.002123401000000000000000000000
1.872000000000000000000000000000,0.002144346000000000000000000000
1.873000000000000000000000000000,0.002165289000000000000000000000
1.874000000000000000000000000000,0.002186231000000000000000000000
1.875000000000000000000000000000,0.002207171000000000000000000000
1.876000000000000000000000000000,0.002228110000000000000000000000
1.877000000000000000000000000000,0.002249047000000000000000000000
1.878000000000000000000000000000,0.002269982000000000000000000000
1.879000000000000000000000000000,0.002290916000000000000000000000
1.880000000000000000000000000000,0.002311849000000000000000000000
1.881000000000000000000000000000,0.002332780000000000000000000000
1.882000000000000000000000000000,0.002353709000000000000000000000
1.883000000000000000000000000000,0.002374637000000000000000000000
1.884000000000000000000000000000,0.002395563000000000000000000000
1.885000000000000000000000000000,0.002416488000000000000000000000
1.886000000000000000000000000000,0.002437412000000000000000000000
1.887000000000000000000000000000,0.002458333000000000000000000000
1.888000000000000000000000000000,0.002479253000000000000000000000
1.889000000000000000000000000000,0.002500172000000000000000000000
1.890000000000000000000000000000,0.002521089000000000000000000000
1.891000000000000000000000000000,0.002542005000000000000000000000
1.892000000000000000000000000000,0.002562919000000000000000000000
1.893000000000000000000000000000,0.002583832000000000000000000000
1.894000000000000000000000000000,0.002604743000000000000000000000
1.895000000000000000000000000000,0.002625652000000000000000000000
1.896000000000000000000000000000,0.002646560000000000000000000000
1.897000000000000000000000000000,0.002667466000000000000000000000
1.898000000000000000000000000000,0.002688371000000000000000000000
1.899000000000000000000000000000,0.002709275000000000000000000000
1.900000000000000000000000000000,0.002730177000000000000000000000
1.901000000000000000000000000000,0.002751077000000000000000000000
1.902000000000000000000000000000,0.002771976000000000000000000000
1.903000000000000000000000000000,0.002792873000000000000000000000
1.904000000000000000000000000000,0.002813769000000000000000000000
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\title{Laboratory Report 1}
\author{John Doe}

\date{\today}

\maketitle
\newpage

\section{Problem 1}

\paragraph{Question\newline}

Question Text

\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,5)
      to [battery2 = $12V$] (0, 0) % The DC power source
      to [short] (2,0)
      to (2, -0) node[ground]() {}
      to [short] (2,0) 
      to [short] (4,0)
      to [short] (4,1)
      to (4, 1) node[nigfete](CD4007NM){CD4007NM} %The transistor
      (CD4007NM.base) node[anchor=east] {}
      (CD4007NM.collector) node[anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm] {}
      (CD4007NM.emitter) node[anchor=north] {}
      (CD4007NM.collector) to[short] ++(0,1)
      (CD4007NM.base) to[short] ++(0,1.26)
      to [short] (4, 2)
      to[R=$100\Omega$] (4, 5) % The resistor
      to [short] (0, 5);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Fig Text}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Answer\newline}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {DC Transfer Characteristic},
        xlabel = {Current (A)},
        ylabel = {Voltage (V)},
        xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 0.16,
         xtick = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
         ytick = {0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16},
        legend pos=north west,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
    ]
    
    \addplot table[col sep=comma,x=X,y=Y] {test.csv};
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\caption{Fig text}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously there are many things one can improve, but you see a tiny bit of a plot. Why only a tiny bit? Because the plot data has only very small overlap with the area under consideration:

```
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 0.16,
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one list thing, the bit at the top, (`\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.csv}`), is that where you've copied the contents of the external file into the LaTeX file or is that still in the separate file? Also yea, I know it's not that big a plot, it's more because the actual full datafile is over 100000 values big and I didn't want to copy it all into the question field.

Comment: @dbradley This is a way to produce the data file from the tex file. You won't need it on your file system if you have the data file already, but this trick makes it very convenient to build minimal working examples since one only has to share one file. BTW, I'd recommend to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` (or `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`) and `\centering` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: OK, um sorry, one other thing, I copied your code into my LaTeX editor and it's still doing a lot of complaining about a missing begin document and when I use mostly my own code but replace the \addplot it's complaining about it containing invalid characters? I'll add the centering and version requirement now also!

Comment: @dbradley My code above has a `\begin{document}`. I have verified that it compiles with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex`. I also have verified that it does not contain any non-ASCII characters. That is, I fail to reproduce any of the issues you mention. Possibly something went wrong when copying the above code?